# Correctly set return of a function between base and derived class

Tags: c++, class, oop, types

I have a problem with the following task. I have two classes `Config`(base) and `Ising`(derived) each of which has a `std::array` of 12 `bool`. I created a function `Incr()` which does the following

-if the i-th elem of the array is false `Incr()` sets it as true and exit;

-if the i-th elem of the array is true sets it as false and then moves to the i+1-th elem.

`Incr()` must work if I call it twice (as in `foo.Incr().Incr()`) so I thought it should return a reference to a `Config`

I am now required (it is an exercise )to create an `std::vector` of 4096 `Ising` object all created via application of `Incr()` to the preceding `Ising` object. Fact is that this function returns a `Config`...

I can set it to return a `Ising` but this seems a very poor design choice to have a base class method which returns an object of its derived class.

I was wondering whether there is a more elegant way to do this

This is what I am working with:

```cpp
class Config {
public:

//ctor
  Config(){
    for(auto i=m_arr.begin(); i !=m_arr.end(); i++){
      *i = false;
    }
  };

//incr function
  Config& Incr(){
    for(auto i = m_arr.begin(); i != m_arr.end(); i++){
      if(*i ==false){*i = true; return *this;}
      else{
        *i=false; 
      }
    }
     return *this;
  };

private:
  std::array<bool,12> m_arr;

};


class Ising: public Config{
public:
  Ising(double g =1): m_g(g){
    };


private:
  double m_g;
};

int main(){
  Config f; //check ctor
  Ising is(3);
  is.Incr();
  std::vector<Ising> vec;
  vec.push_back(is);
  for(int i=0; i < 4096; i++){
    vec.push_back(vec[i].Incr());
 }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who will help

Comment: Since you KNOW in your example that that `vec[i].Incr()` returns a reference to a `Config` that is actually an `Ising`, it can be explicitly converted to a `Ising`.   Bear in mind that a vector's `push_back()` copies the value - it doesn't store a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with this? No need for a redesign.

```
Ising is(3);
is.Incr();
std::vector<Ising> vec;
vec.push_back(is);
for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
    vec[i].Incr();
    vec.push_back(vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: the problem here seems to be that I am trying to pushback in a vector of Ising (which is the derived class) with elements that are Config(the base class). As a consequence the .cpp won't compile. But the point is that in order to Incr() and then pusback I need Incr() to return a Ising not a Config.

Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @JacquesLeen Are you saying my code doesn't compile? Are you saying it doesn't do what you want it to? It looks OK to me.

Comment: nevermind I was referring to my previous example... yours works